# What changes should I make in the script of the package.json file of a MERN app before deploying on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, package.json, mern

What changes should I make in the script of package.json file in my root folder of a MERN app which also contains a separate frontend_client and backend_server sub root folders?

Right now my package.json file in the root folder looks like below which I have committed to the remote Heroku git and it has been successfully compiled but on launching the app I get errors as shown in the Heroku logs

```
{
  "name": "root",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "concurrently \"cd backend_server && npm run dev\" \"cd frontend_client && npm start\"",
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/nishant-k-290195/p1.git"
  },
  "author": "Nishant Kumar",
  "license": "ISC",
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.18.3"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/nishant-k-290195/p1/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/nishant-k-290195/p1#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^5.3.0"
  }
}
```

Below is the heroku logs-

```
2020-09-05T17:33:43.489116+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-09-05T17:33:43.528008+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-09-05T17:34:31.525583+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fast-anchorage-34297.herokuapp.com request_id=57a25f1b-6d5b-4549-8f7b-8cd87dce4267 fwd="183.83.146.132" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-09-05T17:34:32.283997+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fast-anchorage-34297.herokuapp.com request_id=d8cd0ef2-d1db-4a8a-b3a1-0c4aca202e22 fwd="183.83.146.132" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-09-05T17:41:22.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user nishant290195.nkr@gmail.com
2020-09-05T17:41:42.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/a283d1cf-d0fe-41b3-b8da-73c343355213/activity/builds/2e47b96c-e89d-46d3-8eeb-a045848df017
2020-09-05T17:55:39.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user nishant290195.nkr@gmail.com
2020-09-05T17:55:54.797062+00:00 app[api]: Deploy c0d16916 by user nishant290195.nkr@gmail.com
2020-09-05T17:55:54.797062+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user nishant290195.nkr@gmail.com
2020-09-05T17:55:55.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-09-05T17:55:58.414761+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-09-05T17:56:00.690083+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm run dev`
2020-09-05T17:56:03.649588+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-09-05T17:56:03.649613+00:00 app[web.1]: > root@1.0.0 dev /app
2020-09-05T17:56:03.649614+00:00 app[web.1]: > concurrently "cd backend_server && npm run dev" "cd frontend_client && npm start"
2020-09-05T17:56:03.649615+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-09-05T17:56:03.664007+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: concurrently: not found
2020-09-05T17:56:03.669157+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-09-05T17:56:03.669442+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2020-09-05T17:56:03.669852+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2020-09-05T17:56:03.670220+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2020-09-05T17:56:03.673293+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! root@1.0.0 dev: `concurrently "cd backend_server && npm run dev" "cd frontend_client && npm start"`
2020-09-05T17:56:03.673429+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2020-09-05T17:56:03.673587+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-09-05T17:56:03.673750+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the root@1.0.0 dev script.
2020-09-05T17:56:03.673904+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-09-05T17:56:03.683841+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-09-05T17:56:03.684138+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-09-05T17:56:03.684329+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-09-05T17_56_03_675Z-debug.log
2020-09-05T17:56:03.737366+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-09-05T17:56:03.780816+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-09-05T17:56:03.783639+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-09-05T17:56:05.855472+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm run dev`
2020-09-05T17:56:08.905828+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-09-05T17:56:08.905855+00:00 app[web.1]: > root@1.0.0 dev /app
2020-09-05T17:56:08.905855+00:00 app[web.1]: > concurrently "cd backend_server && npm run dev" "cd frontend_client && npm start"
2020-09-05T17:56:08.905856+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-09-05T17:56:08.925225+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: concurrently: not found
2020-09-05T17:56:08.937713+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-09-05T17:56:08.938054+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2020-09-05T17:56:08.938476+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2020-09-05T17:56:08.938852+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2020-09-05T17:56:08.943832+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! root@1.0.0 dev: `concurrently "cd backend_server && npm run dev" "cd frontend_client && npm start"`
2020-09-05T17:56:08.943985+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2020-09-05T17:56:08.944141+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-09-05T17:56:08.944283+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the root@1.0.0 dev script.
2020-09-05T17:56:08.944404+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-09-05T17:56:08.954584+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-09-05T17:56:08.954809+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-09-05T17:56:08.954944+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-09-05T17_56_08_946Z-debug.log
2020-09-05T17:56:09.036221+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-09-05T17:56:09.078574+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-09-05T17:56:11.011048+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fast-anchorage-34297.herokuapp.com request_id=35e7708e-0cc1-45cb-926f-623d4cde16b0 fwd="183.83.146.132" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-09-05T17:56:11.656448+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fast-anchorage-34297.herokuapp.com request_id=8945408f-d80e-4d57-8ffc-f3bc1e33a8ad fwd="183.83.146.132" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-09-05T17:59:12.714272+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fast-anchorage-34297.herokuapp.com request_id=c2d646c9-f779-488f-b272-29320f87a76d fwd="183.83.146.132" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-09-05T17:59:13.260112+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fast-anchorage-34297.herokuapp.com request_id=445d6125-a6fc-4af6-975c-737091123a89 fwd="183.83.146.132" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-09-05T17:59:15.753473+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fast-anchorage-34297.herokuapp.com request_id=4f4f07df-066e-4eef-b2af-c19b0654f212 fwd="183.83.146.132" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-09-05T17:59:16.257264+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fast-anchorage-34297.herokuapp.com request_id=6f763484-4a76-40b1-a48f-a8b58b1ddc67 fwd="183.83.146.132" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-09-05T18:19:40.404117+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-09-05T18:19:42.639891+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm run dev`
2020-09-05T18:19:45.146091+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-09-05T18:19:45.146144+00:00 app[web.1]: > root@1.0.0 dev /app
2020-09-05T18:19:45.146148+00:00 app[web.1]: > concurrently "cd backend_server && npm run dev" "cd frontend_client && npm start"
2020-09-05T18:19:45.146148+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-09-05T18:19:45.154837+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: concurrently: not found
2020-09-05T18:19:45.159721+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-09-05T18:19:45.159910+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2020-09-05T18:19:45.160045+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2020-09-05T18:19:45.160228+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2020-09-05T18:19:45.162886+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! root@1.0.0 dev: `concurrently "cd backend_server && npm run dev" "cd frontend_client && npm start"`
2020-09-05T18:19:45.162963+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2020-09-05T18:19:45.163063+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-09-05T18:19:45.163163+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the root@1.0.0 dev script.
2020-09-05T18:19:45.163319+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-09-05T18:19:45.171480+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-09-05T18:19:45.171611+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-09-05T18:19:45.171645+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-09-05T18_19_45_164Z-debug.log
2020-09-05T18:19:45.226610+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-09-05T18:19:45.261608+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-09-05T19:10:59.294228+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-09-05T19:11:01.544665+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm run dev`
2020-09-05T19:11:04.141984+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-09-05T19:11:04.142014+00:00 app[web.1]: > root@1.0.0 dev /app
2020-09-05T19:11:04.142015+00:00 app[web.1]: > concurrently "cd backend_server && npm run dev" "cd frontend_client && npm start"
2020-09-05T19:11:04.142015+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-09-05T19:11:04.149729+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: concurrently: not found
2020-09-05T19:11:04.157981+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-09-05T19:11:04.158322+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2020-09-05T19:11:04.158560+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2020-09-05T19:11:04.158822+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2020-09-05T19:11:04.163828+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! root@1.0.0 dev: `concurrently "cd backend_server && npm run dev" "cd frontend_client && npm start"`
2020-09-05T19:11:04.163980+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2020-09-05T19:11:04.164157+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-09-05T19:11:04.164316+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the root@1.0.0 dev script.
2020-09-05T19:11:04.164471+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-09-05T19:11:04.183322+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-09-05T19:11:04.183591+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-09-05T19:11:04.183760+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-09-05T19_11_04_174Z-debug.log
2020-09-05T19:11:04.263772+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-09-05T19:11:04.328653+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Comment: 1. What errors? 2. How does that root package file hook into *any* of the scripts (basically: install, build, prune, start) that Heroku calls?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include relevant details.

Comment: I have added the logs, please let me know what details you need? do you need my folder structure or code in a particular file?

Comment: Heroku strips out ("prunes") your dev dependencies after the build, so concurrently isn't available in the finished dyno. But you shouldn't be running the dev script in prod anyway; it's the *dev* script.

Comment: If you mean to remove the dev script I will remove it but what code should I add instead? I have the react app and node app in two separate subfolders in the root folder. So I can't just add the "start": "node app.js" script in the package.json. What should I do now?

Comment: There should be a start script dedicated to both frontend and backend, right, if not dev?

Comment: If you want to have the backend and frontend on the same server, get Express to serve the built React app (see e.g. I set up I created to do this: https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/wiki/Architecture). If you want two dynos, you'll have to set them up separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- backend's **package.json**
- Replace the file locations in scripts, according to your folder structure
- Here **client** directory has the **react** code and the backend code is in the root itself.

```js
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
```

- **server.js**

```js
const path = require('path');

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // Set static folder
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
  });
}
```